# Trying to expand my show/hide DIV code to target multiple divs efficiently

Tags: html, jquery, css

so I have a long case study, so many images it takes forever to load. So one of the steps I'm taking is hiding all images in a section that are more than 3. I'm doing this in a simple way with show and hide jQuery, and manually adding the target ID to the div I want to show. My question I'm trying to figure out is how I can use this code to target every section, instead of one, since I can only use the target ID once. I don't want to simple copy and paste the code and change the target DIV name, as that is going to be very redundant and certainly the most amateur approach. My pen is located here:

```
<button class="Show">Show</button>
<button class="Hide">Hide</button>
<button class="toggle">Show &amp; Hide</button>
<div id="target"></div>

body {padding:30px;}
#target { display:none;}
.Hide{ display:none;}

$('.Show').click(function() {
    $('#target').show(200);
    $('.Show').hide(0);
    $('.Hide').show(0);
});
$('.Hide').click(function() {
    $('#target').hide(500);
    $('.Show').show(0);
    $('.Hide').hide(0);
});
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('#target').toggle('slow');
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use a classname instead of the id, just give all the elements a class target and use $('.target'), this will however change all targets at once... other way: have all .target elements call a function with itself as an parameter, and toggle that, u can also use a data attribute...

Comment: Is toggle redundant code?  Make a snippet.

Comment: I think that you need to clarify this question a bit. Do you expect the buttons to show and hide all pictures at once or do you have a button per picture?

Comment: I have 10 sections. Each section has 3-7 images that take up the entire row. I want each section to have 3 images or 3 rows, and the option to reveal all the other rows if they click the button.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ragax/pen/PoYxEKL is the link

Comment: I want to be able to target multiple divs with the same code except as unique targets.

Comment: The codepen is for one div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean and what you want to do, but you can use it this way instead of a few different functions.

As far as I understand you want to use css classes as well?

```
.hide{display:none}

$("button").click(function() {
$("button").removeClass("hide");
$(this).addClass("hide")
})
```

I tried to be helpful in a very simple way for you, I hope it will be useful.